# python search pattern in file and discard repeatitive ones

Tags: python, search, match

file.txt

```
1349 cyc MNR4____ (00110408:0000004f) 0000e004 00005555
1349 cyc MNR4____ (00110408:0000004f) 0000e004 00005555
1349 cyc MNR4____ (00110408:0000004f) 2002e004 00005555
1349 cyc MNR4____ (00110408:0000004f) 0000e004 00005555
1349 cyc MNR4____ (00110408:0000004f) 0000e004 00005555
1349 cyc MNR4____ (00110408:0000004f) 2002e001 2002e004
1349 cyc MNR4____ (00110408:0000004f) 2002e004 2002e003
```

---

Need help to write code to search the following:
Dump only `2002xxxx` from the 5th column without repeating.

so output of above file should be:

```
2002e004
2002e001
```

Comment: What code do you have so far, and how is it deficient?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt') as infile:
    vals = set()
    for line in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'):
        val = line[-2]
        if val.startswith('2002'):
            vals.add(val)
for val in vals:
    print(val)
```